# How to use deamdify transform

Tags: browserify

I have a simple AMD utility library. I am trying to use with the `deamdify` browserify transform.

```
define(function() {                                                                                                                                                                          
  return {                                                                                                                                                                                   
    add: function(num1, num2) {                                                                                                                                                              
      return num1 + num2;                                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                                                        
  };                                                                                                                                                                                         
});
```

I tried running the transform:
`browserify -t deamdify util.js -o bundle.js`

then in a seperate `main.js` file I tried importing the file

```
var util = require('bundle');
console.log(util.add(1, 2));
```

I tried running this with node but `util.add` is undefined so the `console.log` is not printed and an error is thrown (`undefined is not a function`)

Am I using the transform incorrectly? I tried making this as simple as a could.

Comment: I believe you are using browserify incorrectly.  The point is to generate a single file that can be loaded within a browser.  It doesn't expose a module which is what it looks like you are trying to do.

Comment: You're probably right. This was a work related question and I have since moved on, but I believe the end goal was to convert a 3rd party project that uses AMD to be converted to Common or ES6. We load the module conditionally so there was no reason in bundling into 1. I know Webpack (and maybe even browserify) allows this kind of algebra so I'll have to look into that.